# android preferences causing error

Tags: java, android, preferences, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

I am trying to add some preferences abilities into my application. I want the application to be able to load default values that are set in an XML file and then be able to change those values later. I ran across Preferences and have been trying to implement in my code. I worked out the code below and when trying to run the code between the **"//STARTING HERE"** and **"//ENDING HERE"** comments in my **SmartApp** class it does not launch my gui (the screen is blank and does not appear to be doing anything) and gives the following logcat messages. When i run with that area commented out, the application runs like normal. Can someone please take a look at what i have and see what i might be doing wrong or have suggestions for what i might need to fix this issue? If you have any questions or need more information, please let me know. **Thanks in advance**, if i find the solution i will post it here.

---

```
//The log cat messages
02-01 22:49:19.653: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher: 43150 ms (total 43150 ms)
02-01 22:49:24.513: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
02-01 22:49:25.560: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{43f017d0 cpe495.smartapp/.SmartApp}
02-01 22:49:29.393: DEBUG/KeyguardViewMediator(59): pokeWakelock(5000)
02-01 22:49:29.613: DEBUG/KeyguardViewMediator(59): pokeWakelock(5000)
02-01 22:49:29.862: INFO/ARMAssembler(59): generated scanline__00000077:03545404_00000004_00000000 [ 47 ipp] (67 ins) at [0x337450:0x33755c] in 1480914 ns
02-01 22:49:29.952: INFO/ARMAssembler(59): generated scanline__00000177:03515104_00001001_00000000 [ 91 ipp] (114 ins) at [0x337560:0x337728] in 1085613 ns
02-01 22:53:59.112: DEBUG/SntpClient(59): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

---

```
//The Array Values
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string-array name="heartRateBaseArray">
<item>10 bpm</item>
<item>20 bpm</item>
<item>30 bpm</item>
<item>40 bpm</item>
<item>50 bpm</item>
<item>60 bpm</item>
<item>70 bpm</item>
<item>80 bpm</item>
<item>90 bpm</item>
<item>100 bpm</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="heartRateBaseValues">
<item>10</item>
<item>20</item>
<item>30</item>
<item>40</item>
<item>50</item>
<item>60</item>
<item>70</item>
<item>80</item>
<item>90</item>
<item>100</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="sI1Array">
<item>0</item>
<item>5</item>
<item>10</item>
<item>15</item>
<item>20</item>
<item>25</item>
<item>30</item>
<item>35</item>
<item>40</item>
<item>45</item>
<item>50</item>
<item>55</item>
<item>60</item>
<item>65</item>
<item>70</item>
<item>75</item>
<item>80</item>
<item>85</item>
<item>90</item>
<item>95</item>
<item>100</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="sI1Values">
<item>0</item>
<item>5</item>
<item>10</item>
<item>15</item>
<item>20</item>
<item>25</item>
<item>30</item>
<item>35</item>
<item>40</item>
<item>45</item>
<item>50</item>
<item>55</item>
<item>60</item>
<item>65</item>
<item>70</item>
<item>75</item>
<item>80</item>
<item>85</item>
<item>90</item>
<item>95</item>
<item>100</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

---

```
//The settings.xml file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Profile Settings">
<EditTextPreference android:title="First Name" android:key="firstNameKey" android:selectable="false"></EditTextPreference><EditTextPreference android:title="Last Name" android:key="lastNameKey" android:selectable="false"></EditTextPreference>
<EditTextPreference android:title="User Name" android:key="userNameKey" android:selectable="false"></EditTextPreference>
<EditTextPreference android:title="Birth Date" android:key="birthDateKey" android:selectable="false"></EditTextPreference>
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Configuration Settings"><ListPreference android:title="Medium Stress Index Threshold" android:entryValues="@array/sI1Values" android:entries="@array/sI1Array" android:key="sI1Key"></ListPreference><ListPreference android:title="High Stress Index Threshold" android:entryValues="@array/sI1Values" android:entries="@array/sI1Array" android:key="sI2Key"></ListPreference><EditTextPreference android:title="Weight 1" android:key="weight1Key"></EditTextPreference>
<EditTextPreference android:title="Weight 2" android:key="weight2Key"></EditTextPreference>
<EditTextPreference android:title="Weight 3" android:key="weight3Key"></EditTextPreference>

<ListPreference android:entryValues="@array/heartRateBaseValues" android:entries="@array/heartRateBaseArray" android:defaultValue="60" android:key="heartRateBaseKey" android:title="Heart Rate Base"></ListPreference>
<EditTextPreference android:title="Heart Rate Variability Minimum" android:key="hRVMinKey"></EditTextPreference>
<EditTextPreference android:title="Heart Rate Variability Maximum" android:key="hRVMaxKey"></EditTextPreference>


</PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

---

```
//The preferences class
package cpe495.smartapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    }
}
```

---

```
//The Main Class
public class SmartApp extends Activity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
    TextView smartConnectionStatus;
    TextView testOutputView;
    Thread cThread;
    private ConnectDevice cD = new ConnectDevice();
    private DataRobot dR = new DataRobot();
    private DataBuilder dB = new DataBuilder();
    private DataSender dS = new DataSender();
    public SmartApp() {
        /* Constructor */
        cD.addDataReceivedListener(new DataReceivedListener() {
            @Override
            public void dataReceivedReceived(DataReceivedEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dR.analyzeData(event.getData());
            }
        });
        dR.addDataAnalyzedListener(new DataAnalyzedListener() {
            @Override
            public void dataAnalyzedReceived(DataAnalyzedEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dB.submitData(event.getData());
            }
        });
        dB.addDataBuilderListener(new DataBuilderListener() {
            @Override
            public void dataBuilderReceived(DataBuilderEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dS.sendData(event.getData());
            }
        });
    }
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.intro);

        //STARTING HERE
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

        //set remembered preferences
        dR.sethRB(Integer.parseInt((prefs.getString("heartRateBaseKey", null))));
        dR.sethRVMax(Integer.parseInt((prefs.getString("hRVMaxKey", null))));
        dR.sethRVMin(Integer.parseInt((prefs.getString("hRVMinKey", null))));
        dR.setsI1(Integer.parseInt((prefs.getString("sI1Key", null))));
        dR.setsI2(Integer.parseInt((prefs.getString("sI2Key", null))));
        dR.setW1(Integer.parseInt((prefs.getString("weight1Key", null))));
        dR.setW2(Integer.parseInt((prefs.getString("weight2Key", null))));
        dR.setW3(Integer.parseInt((prefs.getString("weight3Key", null))));
        //ENDING HERE            


        smartConnectionStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.smartConnectionStatus);
        testOutputView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testingOutput);

        final Button firstTimeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.firstTimeButton);
        firstTimeButton.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent userCreationIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), UserCreation.class);
                startActivityForResult(userCreationIntent, 0);

            }
        });

        final Button connectDeviceButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connectDeviceButton);
        connectDeviceButton.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {    
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Intent connectDeviceIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ConnectDevice.class);
                //startActivityForResult(connectDeviceIntent, 0);

                cThread = new Thread(cD);
                cThread.start();
            }
        });

        final Button disconnectDeviceButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.disconnectDeviceButton);
        disconnectDeviceButton.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                cD.setConnected(false);
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs,
            String key) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(key.equals("heartRateBaseKey")) {
            dR.sethRB(Integer.parseInt((prefs.getString("heartRateBaseKey", null))));
        }
        else if(key.equals("hRVMaxKey")) {
            dR.sethRVMax(Integer.parseInt((prefs.getString("hRVMaxKey", null))));
        }
        else if(key.equals("hRVMinKey")) {
            dR.sethRVMin(Integer.parseInt((prefs.getString("hRVMinKey", null))));
        }
        else if(key.equals("sI1Key")) {
            dR.setsI1(Integer.parseInt((prefs.getString("sI1Key", null))));
        }
        else if(key.equals("sI2Key")) {
            dR.setsI2(Integer.parseInt((prefs.getString("sI2Key", null))));
        }
        else if(key.equals("weight1Key")) {
            dR.setW1(Integer.parseInt((prefs.getString("weight1Key", null))));
        }
        else if(key.equals("weight2Key")) {
            dR.setW2(Integer.parseInt((prefs.getString("weight2Key", null))));
        }
        else if(key.equals("weight3Key")) {
            dR.setW3(Integer.parseInt((prefs.getString("weight3Key", null))));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are a couple of issue with this code.  The first is that the default values you have are all `null` when loading from your preferences.  The documentation for [`Integer#parseInt()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) states that it will throw a `NumberFormatException` if you pass in `null`.  Use `0` or some other value instead.

The second is that I think all your calls to the `dR` methods are taking a long time to complete.  What do these functions do?  I'm betting that they are somewhat intensive tasks, and since they are in your `onCreate()` method the operating system thinks that your app has taken too long to start and thus kills it.  Move these calls out into an `AsyncTask` so that they can be loaded in the background.

- [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
- [Painless threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html)

Comment: the dR methods are not taking long at all. It is just assigning those values to the classes private values. Do you know how i the preferences to accept the default values that are set in the xml? I thought setting that to null would make it take the default values from the xml file, instead of the one set in parseInt. Will let you know my results.

Comment: Check the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getString%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).  The second parameter is the value *returned* by `getString` if the preference is not found.  Please note that there is a `getInt()` method, so you could store the `int` values directly.